# What would be the value of "variable" in this instance? I am not sur ehow to use trunc in SAS

Tags: sas

Variable = trunc(2.4857,3)

What does this do? And what would be the value of "variable"? TY! I have tried researching online but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the help page? [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40sas.com%20TRUNC()%20function) [First Hit](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1lfp83m4yht68n1luxn5tnmuhp3.htm&locale=en)

> The TRUNC function truncates a full-length number (stored as a double
> number) to a smaller number of bytes, as specified in length, and pads
> the truncated bytes with 0s. The truncation and subsequent expansion
> duplicate the effect of storing numbers in less than full length and
> then reading them.

The way to tell what the result of zeroing out 5 out of the 8 bytes SAS uses to store floating point numbers would be to run a data step and check the results.

```
7     data test;
8       before=2.4857 ;
9       after=trunc(before,3);
10      put 'BEFORE: ' before best20. ' HEX: ' before hex16. ;
11      put 'AFTER : ' after  best20. ' HEX: ' after hex16. ;
12    run;

BEFORE:               2.4857 HEX: 4003E2B6AE7D566D
AFTER :         2.4853515625 HEX: 4003E20000000000
```